# CKEditor close dialog

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to call close function for CKEditor dialog box from my custom plugin. Just like it happens when you are clicking on smile in "smileys" plugin, but I can't find out how can I do the same in my own plugin.
Thanx for reply!

I've got the solution.
In my plugin I needed to call close function from "CKEDITOR.dialog.add" in "onLoad" section. So, I have to do this:

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'plugin_name', function( editor ){
    onLoad: function( event ){
        [...some code...]
        event.sender.hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23):

`CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent().hide()`

Answer (score 4):

I propose you do it the same way it is done by CKEditor Dialog plugin internally. See line 535 in [plugin.js](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/dialog/plugin.js#L535)

By clicking the button or firing the cancel event you ensure correct handling by the plugin.

Code sample:

```
// If there's a Cancel button, click it, else just fire the cancel event and hide the dialog.
        button = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent().getButton( 'cancel' );
        if ( button )
            CKEDITOR.tools.setTimeout( button.click, 0, button );
        else {
            if ( CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent().fire( 'cancel', { hide : true } ).hide !== false )
            CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent().hide();
        }
```